# Pandas - check columns before join/merge dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, join, dataframe, merge

I have a dataframe containing users, each with multiple ids:

```
df_id = pd.DataFrame({'group': ['a','a','b','b','a','a','b','b','a','a','b','b'],
                      'id1': ['erd','hgf','ewr','fgv','nbg','axc','bcv','ijh','plh','wqe','mnf','iud'],
                      'id2': ['dfg','bcw','urz','fwq','nfg','dfo','hiy','fgl','vcw','erq','dfi','vcs']})

df_id

   group  id1  id2
0      a  erd  dfg
1      a  hgf  bcw
2      b  ewr  urz
3      b  fgv  fwq
4      a  nbg  nfg
5      a  axc  dfo
6      b  bcv  hiy
7      b  ijh  fgl
8      a  plh  vcw
9      a  wqe  erq
10     b  mnf  dfi
11     b  iud  vcs
```

2 other dataframes containing partial user ids:

```
df_1 = pd.DataFrame({'uid1': ['ewr','nbg','hiy','dfg','wqe'],
                   'q': [1,1,0,1,0]
                   })

df_1

   q uid1
0  1  ewr
1  1  nbg
2  0  hiy
3  1  dfg
4  0  wqe

df_2 = pd.DataFrame({'uid2': ['urz','nbg','axc','fgl','vcw'],
                   'q': ['low','high','low','high','high']
                   })

df_2

      q uid2
0   low  urz
1  high  nbg
2   low  axc
3  high  fgl
4  high  vcw
```

I'd like to merge all 3 together based on the id, however, `uidx` could match either `id1` or `id2` in `df_id` so I cant join on a single column. Furthermore, `df_id` contains more users than either of the other 2 dataframes, so I'm expecting a lot of `NaN`

The only way I can think to do this merge/join is to iterate through `df_id` and check both `id` columns and manually add values from the other dataframes, but this is very slow. Whats the correct way to do this merge/join given that the value I want to join on could be in either `id` column?

The desired output is:

```
   group  id1  id2  q_1   q_2
0      a  erd  dfg  1.0   NaN
1      a  hgf  bcw  NaN   NaN
2      b  ewr  urz  1.0   low
3      b  fgv  fwq  NaN   NaN
4      a  nbg  nfg  1.0  high
5      a  axc  dfo  NaN   low
6      b  bcv  hiy  0.0   NaN
7      b  ijh  fgl  NaN  high
8      a  plh  vcw  NaN  high
9      a  wqe  erq  0.0   NaN
10     b  mnf  dfi  NaN   NaN
11     b  iud  vcs  NaN   NaN
```

My actual data has hundreds of columns per dataframe, where the column names vary drastically, so I'm look for a way that doesn't require me to handle each column individually/manually. In other words, I'm looking for a general approach that doesn't require me to manually specify column/dataframe names

Answer (score 1, accepted):

generally：

```
df_1 = df_1.set_index('uid1')
q_a = df_id.join(df_1,on='id1')
q_b = df_id.join(df_1,on='id2')
df_id['q_1'] = q_a['q'].fillna(q_b['q'])
```

Repeat this operation on df_2, or extract a function and apply it on df_2. Maybe use `iloc` to avoid using column names.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a method that avoids merging each dataframe multiple times by stacking the original dataframe's multiple `id*` columns into a single `id` column, and then merging each dataframe once against that.  I can't guarantee that this will be faster with your data than a more straightforward approach (but let me know if it isn't).

```
import numpy as np

# Set some initial arguments (you might do this programmatically instead)
id_cols = ['id1', 'id2']
df_list = [df_1, df_2]
q_list = ['q_{0}'.format(n + 1) for n in range(len(df_list))]

# Make a new df stacking all the id columns
s = df_id[id_cols].stack()
s.name = 'id'
df = pd.DataFrame(s).reset_index()

# Merge each dataframe on the id column once
for n, df_n in enumerate(df_list):
    df_n.rename(columns={'q': 'q_{0}'.format(n + 1)}, inplace=True)
    df = df.merge(df_n, left_on='id', right_on='uid{0}'.format(n + 1), how='left')
    del df['uid{0}'.format(n + 1)]

# If there are multiple values that match, reconcile them
df = df.set_index(['level_0', 'level_1']).unstack(level=-1)
df = df.loc[:, q_list].groupby(level=0, axis=1).max(axis=1).replace({None: np.nan})

# Re-merge with the original dataframe
df_id.merge(df, left_index=True, right_index=True)
```

This gives the following result:

```
   group  id1  id2  q_1   q_2
0      a  erd  dfg  1.0   NaN
1      a  hgf  bcw  NaN   NaN
2      b  ewr  urz  1.0   low
3      b  fgv  fwq  NaN   NaN
4      a  nbg  nfg  1.0  high
5      a  axc  dfo  NaN   low
6      b  bcv  hiy  0.0   NaN
7      b  ijh  fgl  NaN  high
8      a  plh  vcw  NaN  high
9      a  wqe  erq  0.0   NaN
10     b  mnf  dfi  NaN   NaN
11     b  iud  vcs  NaN   NaN
```

Comment: This doesnt appear to work. The `q_2` column is full of `nan`

Comment: @Simon not sure why it doesn't work for you - it appears to provide the correct output for me.